# Error "Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugResources'" during building after upgrading React-Native up to 0.59.0

Tags: react-native, gradle, apk

Project doesn't build by command 'react-native run-android' after upgrading react-native from 0.57.1 to 0.59.0. 
Gradle was upgrading in accordance with react-native 0.59.9 changelog: `"future-proof" RN 59 from crashes caused by upgrading Gradle (now can support up to 5.4.1 & 3.4.0 for the plugin)`

Error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Git\limepay-rn\android\build.gradle' line: 39

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not create task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
   > Project#beforeEvaluate(Closure) on project ':app' cannot be executed in the current context.
```

In the Internet and here, on the stackoverflow, they write about changing gradle versions. I tried different combinations of its versions (including those that people designate as workable), but every time there was this error. Clearing the gradle cache did not help either.

Stacktrace

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Kate\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'android',
1 verbose cli   '--stacktrace' ]
2 info using npm@6.5.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'preandroid', 'android', 'postandroid' ]
5 info lifecycle LimePay@1.0.2~preandroid: LimePay@1.0.2
6 info lifecycle LimePay@1.0.2~android: LimePay@1.0.2
7 verbose lifecycle LimePay@1.0.2~android: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle LimePay@1.0.2~android: PATH: C:\Users\Kate\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Git\limepay-rn\node_modules\.bin;D:\Git\limepay-rn\node_modules\.bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Android\tools;C:\platform-tools;C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\Kate\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Kate\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle LimePay@1.0.2~android: CWD: D:\Git\limepay-rn
10 silly lifecycle LimePay@1.0.2~android: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'react-native run-android' ]
11 silly lifecycle LimePay@1.0.2~android: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle LimePay@1.0.2~android: Failed to exec android script
13 verbose stack Error: LimePay@1.0.2 android: `react-native run-android`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kate\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kate\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid LimePay@1.0.2
15 verbose cwd D:\Git\limepay-rn
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Kate\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "android" "--stacktrace"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.5.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error LimePay@1.0.2 android: `react-native run-android`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the LimePay@1.0.2 android script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

android\build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "25.4.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "12.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        google()
        maven {
            // Android patched JS core for mobx v5 support
            // Local Maven repo containing AARs with JSC library built for Android
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist"
       }
    }
  project.configurations.all {
      beforeEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 25
                buildToolsVersion '25.4.0'
            }
        }
    }
     resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
              && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
           details.useVersion "25.4.0"
        }
     }
  }
}



wrapper {
    gradleVersion = '5.4.1'
    distributionUrl = distributionUrl.replace("bin", "all")
}
```

app\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-sentry/sentry.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.limepay"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 6
        versionName "1.0.2"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
        renderscriptTargetApi 23 // Settings from package react-native-blur
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true // Settings from package react-native-blur
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
     // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
                // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
                def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
                def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
                if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                    output.versionCodeOverride =
                            versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
                }
            }
        }
        }

}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-sentry')
    implementation project(':react-native-webview')
    implementation project(':react-native-svg')
    implementation project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
    implementation project(':react-native-blur')
    // implementation project(':react-native-awesome-card-io')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:${rootProject.ext.googlePlayServicesVersion}" // react-native-maps
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${rootProject.ext.googlePlayServicesVersion}" // react-native-maps
    implementation project(':react-native-device-info')
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

// Version conflict fix
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
        force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r224109' // For patched JS core mobx5 support
    }
}
```

gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.0-all.zip
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23516)

try this:

In gradle-wrapper.properties

change`distributionUrl`to`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`
and in root `build.gradle` file change gradle classpath to this: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'`